# Automatically display fxml webview on page start

Tags: javafx, webview, fxml

I am using webview in fxml to display a youtube link in a page, but it is only displayed when the user hovers over it. I couldn't find a way to display it when the page starts automatically.
I am still a beginner and a student in JavaFX.
Movie.fxml:

```
<HBox layoutX="530.0" layoutY="229.0" prefHeight="379.0" prefWidth="587.0" spacing="3.0">
     <padding>
        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
     </padding>
     <children>
        <WebView fx:id="SpiderManWebView" onMouseEntered="#SpiderManTrailer" prefHeight="373.0" prefWidth="592.0" />
     </children>
  </HBox>
```

Please note I am using other elements not just a webview, I've designed it in scene builder.

MovieController.java:

```
@FXML
private WebView SpiderManWebView;

@FXML
void SpiderManTrailer() {
WebEngine WebEngine = SpiderManWebView.getEngine();
WebEngine.load("https://www.youtube.com/embed/Lko8OP9_AjQ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [youtube documentation](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmake-an-embedded-video-play-automatically):

> To make an embedded video autoplay, add "&autoplay=1" to the video’s embed code right after the video ID (the series of letters that follows "embed/").

Sample url from the documentation (not a real playable video link, just a syntax demo):

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/D6Ac5JpCHmI?&autoplay=1
```

> If I don't hover, the webview always shows a white box

If you want to load the video and start it playing when the fxml is loaded, then delete the mouse handler and put it’s work (loading the auto play url) into the initialize method.

Comment: The problem here isn't about auto playing, it's that the whole webview doesn't show up unless I hover my mouse over it.
If I don't hover, the webview always shows a white box.

Comment: But that is exactly what you asked it to do.  You don’t load the youtube page until the mouse enters the web view.

Comment: please add any clarification to your question (along with the [mcve]) instead of hiding it in a comment